# Хранение cache в Tomcat

Tags: кэширование, tomcat

Для чего Tomcat хранит кэш у себя в папке works? Если учесть, что почти все файлы могут измениться, то такое кэширование потенциально несет риски.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat не бездумно использует закешированные классы. Перед использованием он сравнивает время изменения исходного файла с закешированным, и если исходный файл был изменён после создания кэша - закешированный файл пересоздаётся. Кэш же хранится для ускорения загрузки обработки страниц, ведь операция трансляции JSP-страницы в сервлет с последующей компиляцией и загрузкой может занимать значительное время (в зависимости от размера исходной JSP-страницы). Также в кэш складываются ресурсы, извлечённые из библиотек, используемых в приложении. Эти ресурсы точно не могут измениться во время работы приложения, поэтому кэш позволяет сэкономить время, затрачиваемое на распаковку архивов библиотек.

Comment: а что за ресурсы извлеченные из библиотек?

Comment: Всё, помимо классов, что зашили в библиотеку её разработчики. Это могут быть properties-файлы, xml-конфиги, xsd-схемы или любые другие текстовые или бинарные файлы, необходимые для работы библиотеки.